# Adding multiple where clauses using Laravel's Query Builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is my current query:

```php
$logs = LogModel::where('spider_name', '=', $spider_name )->get();
```

How can I add two other `where` conditions?

Answer (score 2):

You can chain as many conditions as you like this way:

```
$logs = LogModel::where('spider_name', '=', $spider_name )
                ->where('column1', '=', $value1 )
                ->where('column2', '=', $value2 )
                ->get();
```

When chaining conditions this way the query will be generated using the `AND` operator. If you need to use other operators such as `OR` you can read more in the [Advanced Wheres](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres) section from the [Laravel Query Builder Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries).

Answer (score 0):

You can chain your `where` calls, or just pass an array to `where`:

```php
$logs = LogModel::where([
    'spider_name' => $spider_name,
    'hobit_name'  => $hobit_name,
])->get();
```

If you have some variables that exactly match the column names, you can use `compact`:

```php
$spider_name = 'Shelob';
$hobit_name = 'Frodo';

$logs = LogModel::where(compact('spider_name', 'hobit_name'))->get();
```